# C# Instantiate a class of any type inside another object and call a method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection

I’m currently trying to write a class that perform EXECUTE-AROUND pattern for any class that is passed to it.

Using rough pseudo code something like this:

```
class MyWrapperClass(){
    private object containedObject;

    public void importObject<MyObject>();
    {
        where MyObject: new ()
        {
            containedObject = new MyObject();
        }
    }

    public void callMethod(Func<int> MyMethod)
    {
        //Wrapped Code here
        containedObject.MyMethod;
        //Wrapped Code here
    }
}
```

The objective is that any object type can be passed to my `MyWrapper` calls to this object can then only be done by via `callMethod`, the goal is to wrap code before and after `MyMethod`.

I have seen that I could do this though reflection but that would rely on me passing the method names as strings to the MyWrapperClass and doesn’t seem like the best way to do it.

The goal – is to write agnostic class that handles converting all the methods to new threads, the object would then block any further calls with the wrapped code until the current method is complete.

The purpose – is to quickly turn any object into thread safe action.  I’ve done this on per object biases for specific functions, but it would be good to be able to have something that does reasonable amount of housekeeping and not duplicate that code.

Edit: Based on Comments
How can I make Func MyMethod) take any method with any number of arguments.

I’m not sure how to call the MyMethod on newly instantiated containedObject 
object – Can myMethod be used like this?

Given current example can MyObject be any object and MyMethod by any method that returns void.

What sort of topics should I be researching to do this. 
Examples with code would be very helpful.

Comment: I would expect your function to be declared `1 being an extension class` 2 using a `where T : class` type construct for example I I want to change all null values to be a string and pass the class name to an extension method I would do the following `public static void ConvertNullToStringEmpty<T>(this T clsObject) where T : class { }` I could post an example then you could use this to change the code to work for what ever you are trying to do

Comment: So what problem are you having writing such a class?  What don't you know how to do in order to do this?

Comment: @MethodMan - I'm not sure I understand - do you have an example

Comment: Anything so generic is going to be really slow compared to explicit code, avoid this unless performance is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.

```
public class Wrapped<T> where T : new()
{
    private T _instance;

    public void New()
    {
        _instance = new T();
    }

    public void Import(T t)
    {
        _instance = t;
    }

    public S Call<S>(Func<T, S> method)
    {
        //do something before
        var result = method(_instance);
        //do something after

        return result;
    }

    public void Call(Action<T> method)
    {
        //do something before
        method(_instance);
        //do something after
    }
}
```

Called like this.

```
Wrapped<StringBuilder> wrap = new Wrapped<StringBuilder>();
wrap.New();
wrap.Call(s => s.Append("WAT"));
wrap.Call(s => s.CopyTo(1, new char[] { 'c' }, 1, 1));
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for,  is it possible for call to take a method with any number of parameters?  If understand correctly - is the append happening on  line var result = method(_instance);

Comment: I think its the syntax on this line I'm struggling with - whats the best topic to read up on to understand it all. public S Call<S>(Func<T, S> method)

Comment: So `method` it a lambda for executing the function you want with any number of parameters.  You can read up on generics here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx.

Comment: In C#, there's no non-weird way to call arbitrary methods with arbitrary parameters via a single call. IMO the above `Call(Action<T> method)` method makes it considerably less awful than my suggestion, so I recommend it. The only possible drawback is that either the class becomes generic, or you have to pass the type parameter to `Call()` as well as to `ImportObject()`. I can't say how much of a problem that is for the rest of your design.

Comment: I see - and action addition, is that for Methods that do not have a return value.  I'll read up on generics and Lambda's and give it a try.   @Ed Plunkett, thank you for your answer also - I was curious to understand the reflection method also. Let me test these out and get back.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant Well, you could assign the return value inside the action: `int n = 0; wrap.Call(o => n = o.Plus(34));` but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you say you want, though I can't say if you'll still want it once you have it.

In real life, you'd be adding a lot of null checking and such to this code.

```
public class MyWrapperClass
{
    private Object _instance;

    public void ImportObject<T>() where T : new()
    {
        _instance = new T();
    }

    public object CallMethod(String name, object[] parameters)
    {
        var parameterTypes = parameters.Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray();

        var methodInfo = _instance.GetType().GetMethod(name, parameterTypes);

        return methodInfo.Invoke(_instance, parameters);
    }
}
```

You seem not to want a generic class, but I could have misread your intentions, so here's that, too.

```
public class MyGenericWrapperClass<T> where T : new()
{
    private T _instance;

    public void ImportObject()
    {
        _instance = new T();
    }

    public object CallMethod(String name, object[] parameters)
    {
        var parameterTypes = parameters.Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray();

        var methodInfo = typeof(T).GetMethod(name, parameterTypes);

        return methodInfo.Invoke(_instance, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, is this effectively using reflection?   Is there any way of doing this without passing the object name via a string.  For example ImportObject(Maths);  CallMethod(Maths.FindPi(3));

Comment: Yeah, it's reflection. I don't think there's any way to avoid a string thing of some kind. The trouble is that `MyClass.Foo` is a *method group*, which is not any kind of first class object in C#. You can take a reference to `int Foo(string x)` as `Func<string, int>`, but there's no single data type that can be a reference to *any* method.

Comment: sunshine's idea with the lambda makes the function call syntax weird, but I can't make any case that it's even half as weird as with mine, so I'd go with the less weird one.

Answer (score 0):

Following your example, if I understood it right, this should suffice:

```
public class Example
{
    public int Execute(int Param){ return Param + 1; }
}

public static ThreadSafeWrapper
{
    public static int ExecuteSafe(object Instance, Func<int, int> Function, int Param)
    {
        lock(Instance)
            return Function(Param);
    }
}
```

To use it just do:

```
var instance = new Example();
ThreadSafeWrapper.ExecuteSafe(instance, instance.Execute, 5);
```